# Как в Nanohttpd использовать https?

Tags: java, https, nanohttpd

Возможно ли это? Если да, то какими методами? У меня NanoHTTPD 2.1.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В классе `NanoHTTPD` есть метод `makeSecure()`, который должен быть вызван перед `start()` для инициализации HTTPS.

Выглядит это примерно так:

```
KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("JKS");
keyStore.load(Files.newInputStream(Paths.get("mystore")), "qwerty".toCharArray());
KeyManagerFactory kmf = KeyManagerFactory.getInstance(KeyManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
kmf.init(keyStore, "qwerty".toCharArray());
SSLServerSocketFactory sslServerSocketFactory = makeSSLSocketFactory(keyStore, kmf.getKeyManagers());

makeSecure(sslServerSocketFactory, null);
```

Пример предполагает, что в рабочей директории лежит keystore-файл  c именем `mystore`, защищенный паролем `"qwerty"`.

---

PS. Если вы никогда не настраивали SSL и у вас нет подписанного ключа, можете создать keystore с самоподписанным ключем как-нибудь так:

```
keytool -genkey -alias myApp -keyalg RSA -keystore mystore -validity 999 - keysize 1024
```

Разумеется, браузер будет ругаться на такой ключ и предупреждать об опасности.

Comment: Спасибо. у меня в Nanohttpd 2.1.1 отсутствует метод NanoHTTPD.makeSecure() ... Он появился позже?

Comment: Да, в 2.1, похоже, этого мтеода еще не было. Обновитесь.

Comment: Браузер ругается на небезопасность - это понятно. Но почему сервер кидает SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: unknown_ca , при первой попытке обращения из браузера, (до принятия браузером "исключения безопасности"). И как бороться с этим исключением?